# OpenSSL SignedData wrong generation

Tags: openssl, certificate

I use following code to create *SignedData* CMS (code heavy simplified).

```
// use partial mode to add signer with custom message digest algorithm
CMS_ContentInfo *content = CMS_sign(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, CMS_PARTIAL);
if (content == NULL)
{
    return -1;
}
// signer certificate, key and message digest algorithm
X509 *userX509 = <...>;
CMS_SignerInfo *signer_info = CMS_add1_signer(content, userX509, <...>, EVP_sha256(), CMS_NOSMIMECAP);
if (signer_info == NULL)
{
    return -1;
}
// add intermediate certificate
if (CMS_add0_cert(content, <...>) == 0)
{
    return -1;
}
// add CA certificate
if (CMS_add0_cert(content, <...>) == 0)
{
    return -1;
}
// store result binary data in memory
BIO *input = BIO_new_mem_buf(<...>);
if (CMS_final(content, input, NULL, CMS_NOSMIMECAP | CMS_BINARY) == 0)
{
    return -1;
}
```

I add two additional certificates to have a certificate chain for validation on server. It generates *SignedData* with wrong certificate chain. I used different combinations but chain always the same: CA certificate -> intermediate certificate -> signer certificate.

As I understand correct order is: signer certificate -> intermediate certificate -> CA certificate.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: I could be totally off the mark here, so take it with a grain of salt. What exactly is your problem? If you are trying solve certificate ordering, I believe you are trying to solve a problem that does not exist. According to [RFC 2315](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2315), Section 6.6, `ExtendedCertificatesAndCertificates`: "It is intended that the set be sufficient to contain chains from a recognized "root" or "top-level certification authority" to all of the signers with which the set is associated".

Comment: BouncyCastle's _SignedData_ and OpenSSL's _SignedData_ have different order of certificates inside `certificates` member. I just want to be sure that order not important here.

Answer (score 0):

The certificates in the CMS signed data `certificates` contain a set of certificates. It is up to the user / verifier to create a trusted chain from it, starting from a trusted certificate in a certificate store, of course.

Comment: Created a wiki answer just to indicate that this question has been answered.